# How to represent a bit vector in java so I can search in O(log n)

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, search

I have a list of elements and I need to create a signature made of bits for each element. I will end up with a list of bit vectors. After that I need to sort that list of bit vectors lexiographically. After that I need to search for a bit vector in the sorted vectors list.

I found that if I represent the signature as a String, sorting will take O(N) and searching will take O(M logN) using binary search, where M is the length of the string signature.

But I found that with numbers in general, sorting takes O(n LogN) and searching will take O( logN) using binary search.

My question is how to represent the bit vector in java so that I can sort lexicographically and achieves the same performance of dealing with numbers in general?

I'm mostly concerned with achieving that O(logN) search time using binary search, as someone claims to achieve this in a paper but doesn't provide any clue how.

Comment: Sorting can *never* take just `O(log n)`. Are the complexities in that statement flipped?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen That's quite an unqualified statement. It can take even O(1) if we introduce constraints on the initial list.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Could you give an example ?

Comment: @guckogucko Also, I think what you are looking for is a BitSet: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html

Comment: Certainly. If the constraint is "the list is already fully sorted", then an O(1) algorithm will do. There are other, far less trivial constraints, which actually occur in the wild.

Comment: I get that you want me to be more specific with my claim, but it seems clear that the problem at hand deals with non sorted elements.

Comment: That italicized *never* just stung my eyes, @Hunter. You also explicitly asked for an example.

Comment: Why can't you represent the signatures as ints (the binary representations of which are you bit vectors)?

Comment: @arshajii You shouldn't assume the 32-bit limit is acceptable to OP.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I understood your intent, I was just curious as to what constraints did exist as I have never encountered any.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen That is quite surprising, I suppose it excuses your initial *never* remark. Here's a quote from Wikipedia's entry on quicksort: "insertion sort handles nearly sorted arrays efficiently". So there is one realistic case. If you are interested in finding out more, Google is waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the suggestion by @Keith, use a `java.util.BitSet`, but extend it to implement `Comparable`.  Implement a lexiographic compare suitable to your domain.  Perhaps tweak `hashCode()` and `equals()` for speed.

At that point you can easily sort the Collection of BitSets, and use a binary search.

Alternatively, as usual, you could write a `Comparator` instead to do the lexiographic compare.